# Redistribute/transform qty from one form to other

Tags: java, algorithm, many-to-many

We are a distribution company where we buy products from supplier /distributor where the products are packed in boxes with a specific pack type and has other attributes associated to them like Branch, Country, Distributor name, etc.

Once these products are in our warehouse, we redistribute or repack them to as per our need and sell them. But if the seller specifies that some of the attributes of the product cannot be changed(We call them as locks), we retain them.

The below image shows issue data from the supplier and the Receive data(Repacked Data) which we do in our warehouse. If the pack type says 1X15 implies that the 1 box contains 15 products. The pack type always starts with 1X[Y] where Y is a variable.

[image: Issue Recv Distribution Snapshot]

Those attributes that cannot be changed are indicated in Locks column. Notice that the Qty that we get from the supplier and the qty we repack are same. Also, the Qty for the locked attribute products is the same.

We have a screen where the user keys in all the supplier data and the repacked data. But the user will not specify how the issue data is distributed or repacked.

My goal is to find a mapping data of the issue qty with the receive qty keeping the locks intact in a fast and efficient way.

Final Map data which we need to generate:

[image: Mapping data Receive Issue]

Comment: 1) There are no images with this post.  That's probably just as well :)  2) SO probably isn't the best place to ask a really broad question like this.  3) You marked the tag "Java".  Q: Do you have a database?  Q: Wouldn't it make more sense to leverage your database for this particular problem?

Comment: Hi @paulsm4 , Just fixed the images not showing in the post.  I do understand this is a broad question but I'm looking for good pointers to start with. The question is more related to solving the distribution logic in Java. I do have a database but the data which I have given is an in-memory temporary data mainly in Entity java objects constructed from various DB tables and views. But if the database can help, I can look into that solution as well. Tq